# wpf loading a gif image animation

Tags: c#, wpf, button, animated-gif

I wanted to do a simple button_click that would load an animated gif and have it loop 3 times.

The closest example which is not a Winform example, is Mediaelement, but how does one load it within the button click?

Can one point me to a tutorial?

```
<MediaElement  Height="113" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Name="mediaElement1" 
               Width="177" Source="giffy.gif" 
               LoadedBehavior="Play" 
               Stretch="Fill" SpeedRatio="1" IsMuted="False" />
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code

Comment: Isn't there a simple code you can use to load this within the button, and not just with the xaml window?  Do you have to install a plugin?

Comment: This code worked, just not when I pressed the button.  It loads on start up.

Comment: mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("animatedgif.gif",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);                        mediaElement1.Play();

Comment: <MediaElement  Name="mediaElement1" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Stretch="Fill" SpeedRatio="1" IsMuted="False" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this one and it is easily installed via the Nuget installer into the project.

[Nuget WpfAnimatedGif](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfAnimatedGif)

Their github page [WPF Animated GIF](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/WpfAnimatedGif) specifies how to set it to loop x number of times.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried using the library as specified in the accepted answer and it did not work. I've done some digging and found out the author of the package had remade the package and called it [XamlAnimatedGif](https://thomaslevesque.com/2015/01/17/a-new-library-to-display-animated-gifs-in-xaml-apps/)

In the blog, the author gives reasons as to why he had to change the old package. However, he did not give much information regarding the implementation of it.

The implementation I've been able to get to work is as below

xml namespace reference

```
xmlns:gif="https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif"
```

xaml code for loading a gif

```
<Image gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="/Assets/loading.gif"
       gif:AnimationBehavior.RepeatBehavior="3x"/>
```

Hopefully this helps